# Как создать список в определенном промежутке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Суть, нужно чтобы создавался **список** от промежутка **n** до промежутка **x**, как здесь:

```
x = int(input("Конец: "))
for i in range(n,x+1):
    print(i)

#Начало: 2
# Конец: 6
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
```

Но если я пытаюсь сделать это же, но со списком

```
a = []
n = list(input("Начало: "))
x = list(input("Конец: "))
for i in range(n,x):
    print(a[i])
```

то выдаёт ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    for i in range(n,x):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Конечный результат должен выглядеть как:

```
a = []
n = list(input("Начало: ")) # 2
x = list(input("Конец: ")) # 6
for i in range(n,x+1):
    print(a[i])

# [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Аргументами range могут быть только числа, не надо пытаться запихнуть в них списки. Чем вас не устроила рабочая конструкция `int(input(`?

Comment: А вообще вся задача решается в одну строку `a = list(range(int(input("Начало: ")), int(input("Конец: "))+1))`

Answer (score 4):

Можно короче

```py
a = [i for i in range(int(input("Начало: ")), int(input("Конец: ")) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

пропустили `append` :

```
a = []
n = int(input("Начало: ")) # 2
x = int(input("Конец: ")) # 6
for i in range(n,x+1):
    a.append(i)
print(a)

# [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится так:

```py
a = [i for i in range(int(input("Начало: ")), int(input("Конец: ")) + 1)]
print(a)
```

##### Пример ввода:

> Начало: 5

> Конец: 10

##### Пример вывода:

> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Использование `_` в данном случае не очень уместно. Обычно так называются переменные, с которыми в дальнейшем не идёт взаимодействия, а вы используете его значение для генерации списка.